# Accidentally moved /usr/bin

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've accidentally moved `/usr/bin` to another location.

Now most of the commands don't work anymore: `sudo`, `cp`...

The OS is not booting and I can't put the directory back as I have no permissions.

I also use zsh, and I suspect there were some zsh related files and symlinks.

How can I move the directory back?

Comment: You will have to boot with live-cd or live-usb and put this folder back to its place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply moved the directory elsewhere (say `/some/where`), then move it back:

```
/some/where/sudo /some/where/mv /some/where /usr/bin
```

`mv` is no longer `/bin/mv` now that Ubuntu has completed the usrmerge.

If you don't have an open terminal in which you can run this, and have trouble opening another terminal, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to get GNOME Shell's prompt for running commands, and then try one of these command:

```
/some/where/gnome-terminal.real -- /some/where/bash
/some/where/xterm /some/where/bash
```

Alternatively, if you have the file manager open, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to open the address bar and go to `admin:///some/where`. This should prompt for you to authenticate and then open that directory in privileged mode, allowing you to move things back to `/usr`.

Comment: I can't, it says: "zsh: command not found: mv"

Comment: Looks like `/usr/bin` is not the only thing you moved.

Comment: Also​ "zsh: ..."? Is your root shell also zsh?

Comment: Yes, zsh is my default shell. And apparently commands like mv, cp are working when I'm in /bin directory. However when I'm trying to move or copy I have no permissions to do it and sudo is not available.

Comment: @CornelAndreev you do know where you moved `/usr/bin` to, right? `sudo` is wherever you moved it, so run it from there. Did you read the answer at all?

Comment: If you can only run mv when in `/bin` that means your PATH is messed up. Reset to a sane default: `export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: Alright, now I moved it back. As you said, I ran the command(sudo mv) from the location I moved it. I didn't know these commands are working like this and I didn't understand all the meaning of your example that I have to run it from the location I moved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To move it back you need superuser permissions.

So navigate to the path where you moved using "cd".Yes, cd command will be available even you move the bin.

Then in the new bin directory

use:

```
./sudo /new/bin/path/mv new/bin/path /usr/bin/
```

`./sudo` to access sudo

`./sudo /new/bin/path/mv` to run mv (move command)

This should move back the folder in it's place.