# moved /usr/bin to Downloads/

Tags: command-line, directory

I accidently moved my `/usr/bin/` folder to `Downloads` using the following command.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/ Downloads/
```

I saw a similar problem like this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951134/accidentally-moved-usr-bin)

But that doesnot work, because I don't have access to my `terminal`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @cocomac i got to tty but I cannot login, there is no response after I type my username

Comment: @vanadium not because I cannot access my terminal.

Comment: Then post a different question: how to access my terminal. Anyhow, if the system is broke, then boot from a live system. You will then need to mount your system drive to move the misplaced directory back, supplying the appropriate paths.

Comment: Remember that your bin path changed, if you try to reach terminal through your gui you have to adjust the path and profile preferences, where custom command resolves to .../Downloads/.../bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist is simple. Boot a live USB, mount the system partition, and fix it. Now, here's how to actually do it:

1. Make a live USB. Directions are [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384358/1438484) (go to the section titled "Creating a Ubuntu LiveCD" and do that) if you don't know how. If you don't already have a live USB (a.k.a. the installation USB stick) you will need to make one *from a different machine*.
2. Boot to the live USB, and do "Try Ubuntu"
3. Open a terminal - I don't use Ubuntu much anymore, so maybe someone else can edit in the name of the terminal app on Ubuntu)
4. Identify the main system partition. I'll use `/dev/sda1` as my example, but use the correct one for you. You can identify it with `lsblk` (run that in the terminal).
5. Mount the system partition somewhere (e.g., `/mnt`). Do `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`.
6. Double-check that `ls /mnt` contains the root direcory of your main OS. If it doesn't, find out where you messed up and fix it
7. Do `sudo mv /mnt/home/[you]/Downloads/bin /mnt/usr`. Replace `[you]` with your username on your real system. Done!
8. Do `sudo umount /mnt` to unmount your system partition
9. Do `sudo shutdown now` to turn off the live USB, unplug it, and when you turn your computer on again, it should work