# Did by mistake sudo mv /usr/bin /usr/local/bin

Tags: sudo, mv

By mistake I did `sudo mv /usr/bin /usr/local/bin` and forgot to put the filename. Now my terminal is not usable. Is there a way to recover from this? I'm from a company laptop and I cannot reformat.

Also, the disk is encripted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidentally moved /usr/bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951134/accidentally-moved-usr-bin)

Comment: Nope, I cannot even open a bash anymore

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Alt` and `F3` and you should get a terminal ... Or reboot to recovery mode ... Or boot from a live USB and mount your root filesystem to move it back.

Comment: Then try https://askubuntu.com/q/1409664/158442

Comment: @steeldriver hmm, yes, I had forgotten about usrmerge, I'll edit it

Comment: @Raffa the terminal won't work because bash, ls, mv, cp...are gone and I could not boot from live USB because of the bitlocker protection and other stuff my company has done to the pc